# Passing data from react to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to integrate react with node so while sending data from react side to node i getting undefined always, please have a look at the below code (get request works fine !)

react side

```
export default class customers extends Component {

postcustomer(){
   customers=[{id:1,name:'xws'},{id:2,name:'sfg'}]
fetch('/form', {
method: 'post',
data: JSON.stringify(customers)
}).then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>console.log(res))
}
  componentDidMount() {
   this.postcustomer()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then in node server

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.post('/form',(req,res)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    console.log(req.body.data)
})
app.listen(5000)
```

so as soon as i run nodemon server.js
req.body.data gives me undefined

Comment: Avoid the phrase "hey guys" in your questions.  We have enough problems with pronoun choice here as it is.

Comment: OK, which line of code is causing the "undefined" error message?  What is the exact wording of the message?

Comment: @RobertHarvey as soon as i run my server js file console.log(req.body.data) gives undefined

Comment: Which means that req is undefined, or body is undefined.

Comment: ya but seems fine everything to me :( i am sending data from react properly i think !!

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: It looks like the server is listening on port 5000, does the client post there?

Comment: @danh the answer is perfect got it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1

You are using `fetch`, not `jQuery`. The content of the request body goes in a property called `body` not `data`

## Problem 2

You forgot to specify the Content-Type so fetch will default to claiming it is sending plain text.

---

```
const customers=[{id:1,name:'xws'},{id:2,name:'sfg'}];
fetch('/form', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(customers),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res=>console.log(res))
```

---

Aside. Don't use implicit globals. Declare variables with `const`, `let` (or maybe `var`).

---

## Problem 3

> ```
> console.log(req.body.data)
> ```

Your JSON doesn't have a `data` property anywhere in it. The top level object is an array.

```
console.log(req.body)
```

Comment: Perhaps mention port 5000 here?